# How to get Metar data using python

Tags: python

So I want to write a python code that will take the latest Metar ONLY and spit it back out.  The trick here though, is that this url constantly updates, but I still want it to take only the latest Metar and spit it out while ignoring the other previous Metars.

So far what I have for code is:

```
import urllib2

import re

URL="http://www.ogimet.com/display_metars2.php?lang=en&lugar=kewr&tipo=SA&ord=REV&nil=SI&fmt=html&ano=2015&mes=07&day=20&hora=17&anof=2015&mesf=08&dayf=19&horaf=18&minf=59&send=send"

f = urllib2.urlopen(URL)

data = f.read()

r = re.compile('<pre>(.*)</pre>', re.I | re.S | re.M)

print r.findall(data)
```

When I run it, it returns back all Metars.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to try one of the metar libraries (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/metar/, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymetar/)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex isn't correct, the `.*` is capturing *everything* -- including the `<\pre>` tag. When I'm using regex for this type of parsing I normally use the form `<tag>([^<]*)`, where the group matches any character except for `<` which signals the next tag; obviously this isn't a super robust solution but is often enough to do the trick. Also, you don't need those flags in your regex. In your case you will have:

```
r=re.compile(`<pre>([^<]*)`)
```

Secondly, `re.findall` returns a list of matches. In Python lists are indexed using square brackets, with the indexing starting at zero; if you want to print the first element of your list, you can call

```
print r.findall(data)[0]
```

Comment: When I add the [0] it still returns all the Metars